# Lexicographical sorting of a Postgres table column based on values of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, say `initial_freq`, in a **PostgreSQL** database (version `10.4`):

```
 initial | freq 
---------+------
 r       |   20
 s       |   20
 a       |   10
 m       |   10
 p       |    7
 k       |    6
 d       |    5
 n       |    3
 g       |    3
 c       |    3
 v       |    3
 b       |    3
 h       |    2
 y       |    2
 j       |    2
 i       |    1
```

The requirement is that whenever there is a tie in the `freq` column,
 the corresponding values in the `initial` column must be sorted
alphabetically.

The **required output** looks like this:

```
 initial | freq 
---------+------
 r       |   20
 s       |   20
 a       |   10
 m       |   10
 p       |    7
 k       |    6
 d       |    5
 b       |    3
 c       |    3
 g       |    3
 n       |    3
 v       |    3
 h       |    2
 j       |    2
 y       |    2
 i       |    1
```

This is a part of a large problem, most of which I have solved except this one.

I realize that this might be a dynamic programming problem, and I can solve it in other programming languages.

I am a complete novice in the SQL world. Any help will be much
appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` to order by `freq DESC` and then by `initial`.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  your_table
ORDER BY
  freq DESC, initial;
```